# Why does XSendfile emit intermittent garbled responses when used with Symfony Components BinaryFileResponse class?

Tags: php, apache2, x-sendfile, symfony-components

**Background**

Part of my application's responsibility is handling requests for static resources (CSS, JavaScript, images) in a controlled manner.  Based on some application logic, it will return one from a selection of different files that might be served on that URL at different times and to different users.  These are therefore static files, but delivered in a dynamic way.

The application is based on Symfony Components and the serving of these static-ish files is handled by the `BinaryFileResponse` class.

The bootstrap code calls the `trustXSendfileTypeHeader` method:

```
\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse::trustXSendfileTypeHeader();
```

The application uses some internal logic based on configuration and the detection and use of `apache_get_modules()` to determine availability.  If [XSendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) is available and the configuration says to use it, it sets the `X-Sendfile-Type` header:

```
if ($useHeader === true) {
    $request->headers->set('X-Sendfile-Type', $header);
}
$response = new BinaryFileResponse($filename);
```

**Problem**

When I run this with the configuration set to never use XSendfile, or through the PHP built-in web server, which obviously does not support XSendfile, everything is perfect.

When I utilise XSendfile, it also works -- most of the time.

Every so often, typically if I press the f5 key 3-4 times in quick succession, "something" wigs out and I get a garbled response.  For example, this is supposed to be a JavaScript file (copied from "Response" tab under "Net" in Firebug):

> hxYîãx��HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Tue, 05 Feb 2013 14:49:10 GMT Server:
>   Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.6-1ubuntu1.1
>   Cache-Control: public Last-Modified: Tue, 29 Jan 2013 13:33:23 GMT
>   Accept-Ranges: bytes Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ETag:
>   "10426f-9f6-0" Vary: Accept-Encoding Content-Encoding: gzip
>   Content-Length: 1011 Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=98 Connection:
>   Keep-Alive Content-Type: application/javascript
>
> ������­VmoÛ6þ,ÿkÀ²ãIý°~q [Üt]
>   XÑt¶H¤@Rv¼Àÿ}w(YS`ÀØ2yïå¹*¾Á>¯¥¥,è) Æ^Ât¸BaÆ\éjgäjí
>   Î&ð*¸Åí¸tY!³Ç$Óe"jÞ![#,n®®oï®A¨þ¸þù××Þ©¼¼ôÇêÚd¹49mv°ÔrtBÖ^;WÍÓÔg´Y¥´FéôÁR9o°35Îà^º­´N=UÐè­Eµ¢XE¸íÒ%ª°¨Úò7¬KñT¾{;£ÈrTnß³étUè{QÀÃ§Ín·:'üJëQÍÄËZeNjOàyÕÁ:#3wö~4Òét1ù$µ`eN)RD|
>   ¶FTØJ·ß½¥¨¸õGç    >9TyÜxzgl-J:) b«9ûAQ½KX`É!yÐÓ]
>   óÆÎ@W¡?¢vún­·7j©ÿ¢ðõÖGEÁy\ºp¤÷cKxf?ï*¼Éç0^ïîÌÇ°ñDQ¸mYJ|4t¾ñæËÛ¯Å
>   ¨6:çøp(}þÑò|LÂ;Õ(#v¹* /[¨U|xª
>   æ]ÍyìjµòÛ¯p?4sI¥"v÷ôp|uQ4ò4&Ï·$eÒc¸   xo%7Ôi´2ñx;`TuÙj23  áÊ%Ä§¿¹lÌwÀS.&ÏØß7¸}ó
>   ZXzå  k2'Zdùè
>   �¦ºû-Ù[Ó²ÿU(¯¤¥=pÃjô¾ç]]Øhhô²×ÙãÚÍ4¨[!Õ}'Òþ^Ð�ûxÿ@+ÚVÞ~áÌáy?d
>   aíD¹·U×ÃÚ]­ õ5íÃø¨o÷ÂAvUÆmÍaày`¦ä©A?mL[-}®(ÿË
>   d°öò¬}Ç¢³Çp1À^6%0 hTô^ts´ÞíWô
>   fO¶ö¢ÎNÜæ·HîUôÔ¶±ÌCµsxh.9åçi  Û·_ÈÞØ_ÄãY_Ö}G<ì°ý2wÔ¿aw8/þù\ã±þ"0C
>   oÂh'tE¶À¤¥7I½éßRt.s?á^d|k/Æ)wRw÷cG¿<Þ
>   ¼´°/^ø*Ê¤AVZ×y¿zÅÎª¥[²Õ1ò_Vµæï_YXÁÕö  ��YXÁÕö ��

Note the presence of the headers in the response body, and the rest of it which is clearly not JavaScript.  There are also some spurious characters at the start, which possibly is what leads to the headers being pushed to the body.  I have tried to determine if this content is the result of gzipping, but I can't confirm that yet.  (See also update below)

**Question**

Firstly, is `BinaryFileResponse` even the correct class to use for serving text (non-binary) files?  The documentation for the class only says "BinaryFileResponse represents an HTTP response delivering a file."  This isn't very detailed but it doesn't say anything about it being exclusively for "binary" files.  However the name has its own implications, why didn't Fabien just call this class `FileResponse`?

Secondly, and more importantly, what could be causing this?  I don't believe it is a browser issue because it is repeatable in both Firefox and Chrome.  Is this a bug in the XSendfile module or in the `BinaryFileResponse` class perhaps?  (I am likely to think it is not the former because I have used it before in a more "raw" way not via Symfony Components, with no such issues).

Has anyone else experienced this?  Any idea where I should even start looking to track this down?  I've looked at the `BinaryResponseFile` source code but it doesn't really do much with XSendfile, just sets the relevant header and prevents content in the response body, from what I can see.

**Update**

I've just noticed a couple of things about these garbled responses:

1. There are no actual headers being sent at all, i.e. on the "Headers" tab in Firebug, for the garbled responses, it only lists Request headers and doesn't even show the heading for Response headers.
2. Even if I set some custom header on the Response in PHP, that header does not appear at all in the garbled responses  (as a header or in the response body), but the custom headers appear correctly for the responses that aren't broken.

Comment: FWIW, this dump looks like gzipped content not being gunzipped, and I notice "Content-Encoding: gzip" is present. I have noticed this in different circumstances with double zipping, once at the php level (buffering output with o_gzhandler) and another time in apache. Maybe this is a direction to examine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me say that I don't have any experience with this Apache module, but I'll try to guide you through a general error deduction:

You should check if you can reproduce it more reliably. While a web browser might be ok to try it out, you should go for something like `curl` and do the request multiple times, for example using a bash `for`-loop.

```
for i in `seq 1 5`; do curl -v http://localhost/xsendfile-url; done
```

The fact that the `Connection: Keep-Alive` header is set and that there are some weird characters before the actual HTTP header lead me to believe that you won't be able to reproduce this problem with separated `curl` calls, because it will open a fresh connection each time. So try this to check if that gives you the weird behavior (curl has keep alive on by default):

```
curl -v http://localhost/xsendfile-url http://localhost/xsendfile-url http://localhost/xsendfile-url
```

Using this, you could go to the [projects github issue](https://github.com/nmaier/mod_xsendfile/issues) page and report your findings. Most probably they will there help you in telling you why mod_xsendfile is behaving the way it is or that you have found a bug.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and certainly makes sense, in fact I was just waiting for the bounty to run out here before I raised a bug. Here's the bizarre thing, this was 100% repeatable, with a web browser at least, I saw it on multiple web servers and browsers, restarted machine, etc.  Now it's disappeared, I can't reproduce it at all. I am using the dev branch of Symfony Components and have updated, so it could have been fixed, however the commit history of the `BinaryFileResponse` class shows nothing interesting (https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/commits/master/BinaryFileResponse.php).

Comment: Marking this correct because certainly, a more reliable/repeatable test than "mashing f5", and then reporting results to the project in the form of a bug, is definitely the right way to go.  I'm just waiting for this to appear again, very curious as to why it would appear and disappear like this.